# Youtube Data Api Page Token Question (python)

Tags: python, youtube-data-api

I try to download the video metadata for year 2019. It exceeds the quota limit every time I run my codes.  I have under 100 videos for that period of time.  Can anyone show me a better way to write the codes?

```
   try: 
    request = youtube.search().list(
        part = 'id, snippet',
        type = 'video',
        publishedAfter = '2018-12-31T23:59:59Z',
        publishedBefore = '2020-01-01T00:00:00Z',
        order = 'date',
        fields = 'nextPageToken,items(id,snippet)',
        pageToken = None,
        maxResults = 50
    )
    response = request.execute()
    nextPageToken = None

    while True:
        request = youtube.search().list(
        pageToken = nextPageToken,
        part = 'id, snippet',
        type = 'video',
        fields = 'nextPageToken,items(id,snippet)',
        maxResults = 50
        )

        response = request.execute()
        nextPageToken = response['nextPageToken']
        items = response['items']
        if response['nextPageToken'] == None:
            break
        for each_item in items:
            video_id = each_item['id']['videoId']
            sub_items = each_item['snippet']
            for sub_item in sub_items:
                video_item[sub_item] = sub_items[sub_item ]

            video_data[video_id] = video_item
except Exception as e:
    print('Error in get_video_data: {0}'.format(e))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please acknowledge that your API call to the [`Search.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) endpoint is running *against the whole set of YouTube videos* of that one year period; your API call doesn't specify any other filtering criteria, which means that your query (upon pagination) would *potentially return millions of video entries*.

If in fact you're looking for your own videos, then your `Search.list` endpoint call should include either the [`forMine`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#forMine) or the [`channelId`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#channelId) request parameters:

- when you've constructed your `youtube` object from the [`discovery.build`](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.discovery-module.html#build) method using its parameter `credentials` (that is you're issuing an authorized request), then use the request parameter [`forMine`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#forMine) as shown below:

```py
request = youtube.search().list(
    forMine = True,
    part = 'id,snippet',
    type = 'video',
    publishedAfter = '2018-12-31T23:59:59Z',
    publishedBefore = '2020-01-01T00:00:00Z',
    order = 'date',
    fields = 'nextPageToken,items(id,snippet)',
    maxResults = 50
)
```

Do note that this alternative proved to not be viable as per the findings documented below under the section *Updates and fixes.*

- when you've constructed your `youtube` object from the [`discovery.build`](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.discovery-module.html#build) method using its parameter `developerKey` (that is you're *not* issuing an authorized request), then use the request parameter [`channelId`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#channelId) as shown below:

```py
request = youtube.search().list(
    channelId = CHANNEL_ID,
    part = 'id,snippet',
    type = 'video',
    publishedAfter = '2018-12-31T23:59:59Z',
    publishedBefore = '2020-01-01T00:00:00Z',
    order = 'date',
    fields = 'nextPageToken,items(id,snippet)',
    maxResults = 50
)
```

Note that `CHANNEL_ID` is the ID of your channel (or any other channel for that matter).

The difference between the two kinds of API calls above is the following: when issuing an authorized request (first bullet above), you'll get all videos of your channel, including those that are non-public (i.e. those that have their [`privacyStatus`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#status.privacyStatus) set to `private` or `unlisted`); on the other hand, when using an API key (the second bullet above), you'll get only the public videos (i.e. those that have their [`privacyStatus`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#status.privacyStatus) set to `public`), even if `CHANNEL_ID` is the ID of your own channel.

---

Now, unfortunately, your code above has another issue: your two `Search.list` endpoint calls are not identical, modulo the `pageToken` request parameter. That's because the second call does not get the request parameters `publishedAfter` and `publishedBefore`.

This difference implies that you're not paginating correctly the result set of your first API call (indeed, even if passing the parameter `pageToken` to the second API call).

Fortunately, the Google's APIs Client Library for Python that you're using implements [API result set pagination](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/pagination) in a simple [pythonic way](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/pagination.html) (I'll exemplify below the case of the second bullet above):

```py
request = youtube.search().list(
    channelId = CHANNEL_ID,
    part = 'id,snippet',
    type = 'video',
    publishedAfter = '2018-12-31T23:59:59Z',
    publishedBefore = '2020-01-01T00:00:00Z',
    order = 'date',
    fields = 'nextPageToken,items(id,snippet)',
    maxResults = 50
)
video_data = {}

while request:
    response = request.execute()

    for item in response['items']:
        video_id = item['id']['videoId']
        video_item = item['snippet']
        video_data[video_id] = video_item

    request = youtube.search().list_next(
        request, response)
```

The code above shows that is not necessary to repeat the first API call in its entirety, with an added `pageToken` parameter; suffices to have the simpler statement:

```
    request = youtube.search().list_next(
        request, response)
```

This statement uses the value of the `nextPageToken` property of the `response` object for to construct from the old `request` object a new one having a properly set `pageToken` property.

---

**Update and fixes**

Upon further tests and investigations with respect to the invocation of `Search.list` with the request parameters `forMine`, `publishedAfter` and `publishedBefore` as above, I came to the following conclusion:

- the parameter `forMine=True` given without any of the parameters `publishedAfter` and `publishedBefore` makes the API call to work as expected;
- the parameter `forMine=True` given along with any of the parameters `publishedAfter` and `publishedBefore` or with both produces the HTTP error `400 Bad Request` along with the JSON error response:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "badRequest"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

Google's own issue tracker records [a very recent bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173534841) that describes precisely the behavior above. The [official response from Google's staff](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173534841#comment3) was the following:

> Status: **Won't Fix (Intended Behavior)**
>
> This is working as intended. Basically you can only set one of the resource filters if it's a for_content_owner request, but both channel ID and published after are resource filters. This requirement doesn't seem to be specified on the developer website: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  When I insert the forMine=True, I got an error, "Request contains an invalid argument".  I tried the same arguments in the google "Try this API" pop-up window, and also got the same error.  I remove "forMine = True" and it works.  So, I make the same changes in my script and re-run it, and I got an error, "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your quota limit".  It is the same error as before.  Is there something wrong with my arguments? I will try again tomorrow with Channel ID.

Comment: @Johnny Tan: Please post the entire error message.

Comment: Here is the error:  Error in get_video_data: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?forMine=true&part=id%2C+snippet&type=video&publishedAfter=2017-12-31T23%3A59%3A59Z&publishedBefore=2019-01-01T00%3A00%3A00Z&order=date&fields=nextPageToken%2Citems%28id%2Csnippet%29&maxResults=50&alt=json returned "Request contains an invalid argument.". Details: "Request contains an invalid argument."

Comment: Do you have `type = 'video'` among the request parameters of your `Search.list` endpoint call?

Comment: The parameter `forMine = True` works for me OK.

Comment: Yes, I did put type = 'video' in the argument lists.  It is required.  I will try again tomorrow because I have already exceed the quota, and let you know.  Thank you so much and  Merry Christmas!

Comment: @Johnny Tan: Merry Christmas to you too!

Comment: @Johnny Tan: Also note that I'm using the client library version 1.7.4. The [latest is v1.12.8](http://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/). Check your version by the command `pip3 show google-api-python-client` (issue it at a Windows command prompt window).

Comment: My is version 1.12.8.  I am running on Mac OS.  Thanks!

Comment: @Johnny Tan: Sorry for posting another comment: indeed I get the same error as yours when having all three parameters `forMine=True`, `publishedAfter=...` and `publishedBefore=...`. With `forMine=True` and without the `published*` parameters works OK. I deem this to be a bug of the API that should be reported to Google via it's [own issue tracker site](http://issuetracker.google.com/).

Comment: Very interesting.  Thanks for finding out the information from issue tracker.  My question is if I can't use both publishedAfter and publishedBefore in the same call, how do I search for a date range?

Comment: Remains valid the other alternative (`channelId = ...`); you may try to issue an authorized `Search.list` call for to see whether the API will include within its result set provided to you video entries that are non-public. Please let me know if you find this to be true. (I myself cannot test this at the moment.)

Comment: I can only confirm to you that `Search.list` worked OK (i.e. without error) when issuing it via an authorized request with `channelId` and both `publishedAfter` and `publishedBefore`.

Comment: OK, I will try it tomorrow and let you know. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It is working now.  I replaced forMine=Ture with channelId.  I don't get the quota limit exceeded error anymore.  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Johnny Tan: But remained my question: did you called the `Search.list` endpoint with `credentials` or with `developerKey`? I wanted to know whether you obtain non-public video entries when calling that endpoint through an authorized request (i.e. using `credentials`, not `developerKey`).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot.  Thank you so much!