# Google Youtube API for scraping all comments from youtube video

Tags: python, youtube-api, web-crawler, youtube-data-api, google-api-python-client

I am trying to fetch all the comments along with replies from the below youtube video link
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kqtD5dpn9C8 using the youtube API in python.
However, the code I am using is going in an infinite loop repeating same sets of comments. I am new in this stuff and seeking for sincere help. The code I am using is given below. TIA.

```
def video_comments(video_id):
li = []
# empty list for storing reply
replies = []

# creating youtube resource object
youtube = build('youtube', 'v3',
                developerKey=api_key)

# retrieve youtube video results
video_response=youtube.commentThreads().list(
part='snippet,replies',
videoId=video_id
).execute()

# iterate video response
while video_response:
    
    # extracting required info
    # from each result object 
    for item in video_response['items']:
        
        # Extracting comments
        comment = item['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['textDisplay']
        li.append(comment)  
        # counting number of reply of comment
        replycount = item['snippet']['totalReplyCount']

        # if reply is there
        if replycount>0:
            
            # iterate through all reply
            for reply in item['replies']['comments']:
                
                # Extract reply
                reply = reply['snippet']['textDisplay']
                  
                # Store reply is list
                replies.append(reply)

        # print comment with list of reply
        print(comment, replies, end = '\n\n')
        li.append(replies)
        

        # empty reply list
        replies = []

    # Again repeat
    if 'nextPageToken' in video_response:
        video_response = youtube.commentThreads().list(
                part = 'snippet,replies',
                videoId = video_id
                       ).execute()
    else:
        break
        
return(li)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Youtube Data API nextPageToken loop in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67270932/youtube-data-api-nextpagetoken-loop-in-python)

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I believe some issues with this part 
   # Again repeat
    if 'nextPageToken' in video_response:
        video_response = youtube.commentThreads().list(
                part = 'snippet,replies',
                videoId = video_id
                       ).execute()
    else:
        break
        
If I get a quick correction for this part, then I wont need to build from scratch. Thanks

Comment: @user19389509 I think the problem is that you're using the *commentThreads* twice, it should be *commenThreads > "if it has replies" > comments*. Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71785217/12511801) for more info.